# Excel VBA Code- Find Values in One Column and Move Data in Next Column Over

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am a bit new with VBA, but I am trying to find code which will search down column E, look for the values "TRUE", and for each one, move one cell to the right of this "TRUE" cell, and cut and paste it one cell to the right.

I have been searching all day, and can't find a solution.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question has been asked many many times...

Comment: If this is homework, check number 3 http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim row
 Dim column
 Dim value

 column = 5

 For row = 1 To 5000 Step 1
    value = Cells(row, column)

    If value = "True" Then
     Cells(row, column+1) = Cells(row, column)
     Cells(row, column) = ""
    End If
 Next
```

This will search the first 1000 rows in the column, any cells that are true will be moved one cell to the right, obviously you need to declare Dim `value`, `row` and `column` before the loop so that it will search the column you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Do you think you could give me an example including the Dim statements?  I don't understand how to structure the syntax.  My value is "True", my column is "E", and I want it to go throw 5,000 rows of column E.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you!  What if I subsequently insert a column before column E, the next time I run the macro, I'm not sure if it will then take the 6th column...  Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Yes, use a unique header title for the column you want to search, then before you run the above code, search your first row for that unique header title, when you find it, start searching that column

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way that I can range name the column and use that in my code? As others will be running the macro, I don't want them to have to do a step prior to running it.  Thank you.

Comment: no step is needed for the user, just an extra step in your code to find the column to be searched. Use the same method as above, except increment column instead of row, then you can check if you are above the right column, once you are, start searching down...